# How to operate a model in django without not define?

Tags: django

There are two projects, the A project defines each model, and the B project queries and modifies the model of the A project. How to do it?

A project:

```
class Case(models.Model):
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

B project:
I thought like this, but I don't know how to continue:

```
class Base(models.Model):
    pass

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
             update_fields=None):
        pass
```

Comment: This is not clear at all. What is the point of Base? Why don't you just import Case?

Comment: This does not look like models at all. A model is an entity you want to persist. Here it looks like your `Base` is not an entity at all.

Comment: Sounds to me like you want to define your models in one app and your views in another app.

Comment: The business is divided into A and B projects, and I want to operate the model of the A project on the B project.

Comment: what do you mean by "operate the model"? And what do you mean by "A project" and "B project" with respect to programming? Are those different Django projects altogether? Different apps in the same project? The same way the `django.auth.User` model is defined in a totally different project, nothing stops you from importing it and using it in your own project. So I don't understand what `class B` is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Project A used database A, Project B used database B. Project A had the model A. I copy the code of model A into the project B to operate the data of model A.